# Breakpoint debugging in Appium

Tags: debugging, logging, appium, breakpoints, appium-android

Is there a way on how to set breakpoints in appium or get a better debugging experience than looking through logs and printing `console.log()` all the time?

I would like to be able to stop the test run in any step and see what are the values - proceed to next step and so on. I saw that this might be possible using IDE but is there a better integration solution? Also saw that cloud device providers provide similar logging solutions like https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/set-up-tests/debugging-options but this is only on the cloud devices and I would like to see it localy.

Maybe a dependency that would include what I am asking for?

My setup is appium, webdriver.io, mocha.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, debug with IDE and BrowserStack logs it's not the same. I don't know why you need it, but the best way to debug is to use the IDE

> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67DTu.png)

> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoHX9.png)

> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPZ4T.png)

Also, you can create your custom logger util, which will store all the events to log file and print it

And the last one is https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/events/get-events/
self.driver.execute_script("mobile: deviceInfo")

Comment: You might want to consider formatting your answer in a more clear and concise manner.